# navigation menue not display properly

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm design a responsive web using html5 and css. my navigation menue not display properly in iphone.It disply horizontal in desktop but display conflict rows in phone. can someone help me. My css code and screenshot is

```
   .body{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;

}

.mainHeader img{
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    margin:2% 0;
}
.mainHeader nav{

     overflow: auto;

}
.mainHeader nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;

} 
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide *all* your code, and drop it in something like [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pen) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide all of your code. There are a few mistakes in your code from what I can see:

- `height: height:100%` should just be `height: 100%`
- You've got multiple display instances in the last style, you need to use just one or the other.